# Mysterious unhandled promise warning from NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

When the below code errors (`ping()` rejects its promise), I get the warning. The HTTP function seems to error out just fine. Something must be happening in `ping()` itself, I guess, which is somehow avoiding the try-catch.

Could someone enlighten me? (This is after a few attempts at changing things to get it working.)

```
(async () => {
    try {
            let webTask, pingTask;

            try {
                    webTask = httpsGet(urls[0]);
            } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e);
            }

            try {
                    pingTask = ping('8.8.8.8');
            } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e);
            }

            try {
                    const webResult = await webTask;
                    console.log('HTTP result:', webResult);
            } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e);
            }

            try {
                    const pingResult = await pingTask;
                    console.log('Ping result:', pingResult);
            } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e);
            }
    } catch (e) {
            console.log('Error:', e);
    }
})();
```

The error is:

```
"main.js" 137 lines, 2945 characters
(node:58299) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: #<Object>
(node:58299) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:58299) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

This is earlier in the file where I define my `ping` function:

```
const netping = require('net-ping');
const pingSession = netping.createSession({
    retries: 0,
    timeout: 10000
});

const ping = ip => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let result = { ipAddress: ip, start: new Date(Date.now()), end: null, error: null, duration_ms: -1 };

            pingSession.pingHost(ip, (error, target) => {
                    result.end = new Date(Date.now());
                    result.duration_ms = result.end - result.start;
                    if (error) {
                            result.error = error;
console.log('rejecting promise');
                            reject(result);
                    } else {
                            resolve(result);
console.log('resolving promise');
                    }
            });
    });
};
```

NodeJS 11.13.0

Comment: When the rejection is logged, where does it point to, exactly? Are any errors logged before the rejection?

Comment: I'd try https://stackoverflow.com/a/46964348/1026 or reducing further: what makes you think the rejected promise that's not handled is the one returned from `ping()`? Nowhere in the message does it say that.

Comment: Use [`--trace-warnings`](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_trace_warnings), it might show more info.

Comment: Start by changing to `const webResult = await httpsGet(urls[0]);` and `const pingResult = await ping('8.8.8.8');` and get rid of the intermediate promise variables and the duplicated `try/catch` es (which really are not needed).  It may be that the interpreter doesn't realize you are handling the rejection later in the code.

Comment: @jfriend00 That is what I had originally when this happened.

Comment: @Nickolay If I comment out the ping part, it goes away.

Comment: @CertainPerformance This is all the output I get for the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`await` is the javascript construct which converts the rejection of the promise to an exception.
That is, `await` is the construct which handles the rejection.

When you write:

```
try {
    pingTask = ping('8.8.8.8');
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

There's no `await` there, so there's nothing to convert the rejection to an exception, or indeed to handle the rejection in any way.

If you're going to call `ping()` without waiting, then you need a more explicit rejection handling.

**EDIT**

Here's a minimal reproducer:

```
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

const test = (ms, msg) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        sleep(ms).then(reject(msg)).catch(console.log);
    });
};

(async () => {
    let task1;

    try {
        const ms = 50;
        task1 = test(ms, "hey");
        await sleep(ms * 2); // otherwise you don't get an error
        await task1;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
})().then(console.log).catch(console.log);
```

> (node:12822) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: hey (node:12822)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
>   error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
>   without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
>   with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:12822) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code. hey undefined (node:12822)
>   PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was handled
>   asynchronously (rejection id: 1)

The `Promise()` constructor starts running `test()`, after 50 ms the promise is rejected but there is *nothing* to convert the rejection to an exception.
If we remove the 100 ms sleep, then `await` registers its "convert rejection to exception" logic onto the promise way before the 50 ms sleep is done, and so when the promise gets rejected ~49 ms after `await` was called, there's a handler to convert it to an exception.

Comment: So, `pingTask` is a promise.  Nothing wrong with that assignment.  Then, later in the code, they do `await pingTask` and it is surrounded by `try/catch` which has full error handling.  I don't see what you're saying is the problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 answer edited to elaborate on the issue.

Comment: @root Originally I had everything in a single try-catch and single-line `var x = await foo()` lines, and that is when I first received the warning. I broke it up hoping to narrow down what was causing it. So if I understand your explanation, I would still need to call `.catch` on `pingTask`, then throw, to fit into the current mess of try-catches, correct? What I was trying to do is run both tasks at the same time; thinking that `await` blocks. Is the only way to do that (if possible at all) to use the promises directly? Edit: or run in parallel but AFAIK that isn't easily possible.

Comment: I rewrote it and can see that using promises directly does run concurrently, while `await` blocks, and I now know that `await` converts the rejection into a throw. It doesn't seem like I can use await and concurrency together reliably. I think I understand now, unless someone corrects me. Thanks!

Comment: @jfriend00 I think the issue is that, if two Promises exist, and one Promise rejects while the other is being `await`ed, an unhandled rejection will occur *even if* the rejected Promise gets `await`ed inside a `try/catch` later. The interpreter doesn't know that the rejected Promise is going to be handled later, because it's currently `await`ing a different one.

Comment: @CertainPerformance - Which is why using intermediate variables to hold the promise BEFORE a `catch` is protecting the promise can cause problems.  I don't write code that way for this reason.  It turns out the OP wanted to run these in parallel anyway to the whole serially `await` logic is just the wrong tool for what they wanted to accomplish.  They probably want to use `Promise.allSettled()` so they can be notified when both operations are done.